# Wordpress menu editor

Tags: wordpress, web

Is there a plug-in that improves the standard menu editor in Wordpress? For example I need to change the attributes "rel" and "class" for menu items not just the "title".

Comment: You might get a response more quickly asking here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already there in WordPress. No external plugins required.

1. Goto Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menus
2. Click the screen Options button on the top left to see advanced options.
3. Now select the `CSS classes` and `Link Relationship` on Show
   advanced menu properties. [image]
4. Now 2 new boxes will appear for every menu. Just add your custom
   class and rel there.

Thats all. Cheers!!!

Comment: I'm stupid idiot forgot about the screen Options =) Thank you!